# Bluemix authentication ios8 with google and facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, ios8, ibm-cloud, google-authentication

I am trying to implement two types of authentication from an iOS8 device in the bluemix platform. I succeeded in adding one type of authentication: google. 
I am using a ADVANCED MOBILE ACCESS module, and I am at the User Authentication part.
It looks from a dashboard like I can only add one type of authentication. However when I remove google authentication, I can add another type.

Can I have both types and how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently supported to use the provided Facebook and Google authentication in the same application for Advanced Mobile Access. However using the Custom Authentication option you can write your own custom authentication logic inside of your application and Node.js application. Using this method the application could handle multiple types of authentication such as Google and Facebook. Here is some documentation on our Custom Authentication:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/security/id_provs/index-gentopic2.html#custom_id_prov

As an example the your application could have a login button for each type of authentication. When the user hits one of the options it is up to the custom authentication code in the application and node.js app to handle this type properly. With custom authentication you could even extend support for other types of authentication such as twitter, basic username/password, etc